# A question about building a project with Gradle in IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

This is a question about building a project with Gradle. In Linux, I can directly go to a specific directory to execute "`./gradlew`"; but when I use JetBrains' IDEA on Windows, how do I use the column on the right to "cd" to a specific directory to execute" `./gradlew`"?

[image]

I hope to get some official documentation.

Comment: I do not believe there is a "cd" functionality per se, but there is a search (you can just start typing from the Gradle Tool Window). To simplify the navigation you can also link/unlink Projects with +/- buttons.

Comment: You can also approach it from Run Configurations end - it gives you a command line-like  interface to pick both Gradle Project and the Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *Gradle* pane ➤ *Tasks*

You appear to be showing the *Dependencies* branch of the *Gradle* pane. Look for the sibling branch, *Tasks*, in that tree hierarchy.

There you’ll find the Gradle commands. Double-click to execute.

See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html#create_project).

---

For other readers…

IntelliJ knows how to work with Gradle.

Open the *Gradle* pane within your project window.

If no *Gradle* pane is available, you may have the necessary plugin disabled. Use the Settings tool to activate the Gradle plugin.

You may choose to use the console pane within IntelliJ to execute Gradle commands on the command-line rather than through the IntelliJ GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can choose execution context and run any gradle tasks like this:
[Operating procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJn5N.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).